# AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly return false in Some Android Phones

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-syncadapter

In my app, there is an account creation section after login which is normally used for syncing app data with remote data.

But if phone is in unstable state,it wont create account and AccountManager.addAccountExplicitly return false.But when i check the account[],it is returning length as 1

```
 AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
                Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.sample.account");
                if (accounts.length == 0)
                {
                    addAccountAndSync();
                }
```

But app is not shown in "Accounts" in Phone Settings.
**Anybody came across this situation.?**

Comment: don't forget to call `setAccountAuthenticatorResult(Bundle)` after every successful login

Answer (score 2):

Was hitting this on N preview (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210466). Forcing a removeAccount and calling addAccountExplicitly again is a temporary workaround until they fix it.